# What to do when change in one UITableViewCell affect how other cell works?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Say I choose to follow or bookmark a catalog. All catalogs that share the same parent will be bookmarked too.

After a call to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` things will sort of fixed.

The thing is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called until the visible cells become unvisible and then visible again.

How do I make visible Cells to refresh again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you simply call `[tableView reloadData];`. This will display the actual data model.

Comment: [tableView reloadData] does not call cell for row at index path for already visible cells.

Comment: The docs <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html> say "Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.". So the visible cells will be reloaded.

Comment: Nope. It's not loaded. Confirmed. cell for row at index path is only called when cells are about to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `visibleCells` and `indexPathsForVisibleRows` properties of `UITableView`. You will need a method to refresh the cell from the underlying data model.